# Not a group by clause in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
        select  wi.MOBILE,hb.TXN_TYPE
        from pbxhbl.WORK_ITEMS wi inner join
        pbxhbl.HBL_TRANSACTIONS hb
        on wi.MOBILE=hb.PAYER_MSVA or wi.MOBILE=hb.PAYEE_MSVA
        where wi.SOURCE_MODULE=2 or wi.SOURCE_MODULE=15 and wi.status=1 and wi.MOBILE 
        select  wi.MOBILE,hb.TXN_TYPE
        group by wi.mobile having count(hb.ID_USE_CASE)=1
        order by wi.MOBILE
```

this is my query its gives me error not a group by clause when i change my query to

```
        select  wi.MOBILE,hb.TXN_TYPE
        from pbxhbl.WORK_ITEMS wi inner join
        pbxhbl.HBL_TRANSACTIONS hb
        on wi.MOBILE=hb.PAYER_MSVA or wi.MOBILE=hb.PAYEE_MSVA
        where wi.SOURCE_MODULE=2 or wi.SOURCE_MODULE=15 and wi.status=1 and wi.MOBILE 
        select  wi.MOBILE,hb.TXN_TYPE
        group by wi.mobile,hb.TXN_TYPE having count(hb.ID_USE_CASE)=1
        order by wi.MOBILE
```

now every thing is right but problem is now i am getting duplicates records how can i solve this problem

Comment: use distinct it will remove duplicate but can't understand what your are trying to achieve

Comment: Did you see you have a select statement before your group by ? are you sure this is the query you're executing ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this query works

```
SELECT DISTINCT WI.MOBILE, HB.TXN_TYPE
  FROM PBXHBL.WORK_ITEMS WI
 INNER JOIN PBXHBL.HBL_TRANSACTIONS HB
    ON WI.MOBILE = HB.PAYER_MSVA
    OR WI.MOBILE = HB.PAYEE_MSVA
 WHERE WI.SOURCE_MODULE = 2
    OR WI.SOURCE_MODULE = 15
   AND WI.STATUS = 1
 GROUP BY WI.MOBILE, HB.TXN_TYPE
HAVING COUNT(HB.ID_USE_CASE) = 1
 ORDER BY WI.MOBILE
```

Comment: in this case duplicates records are coming